# How do I get the correct position of the escape character?

Tags: python, string, find

Take this variable

```
str = 'how{"to\"get\"this"}position'
```

I want to get the position of the string `\"`, it should be 7

`print str.find('\"')` return 4, because of the escape character.

`print str.find('\"')` or `('\')` or `(r'\')`, return -1, no result

so what substr I should use to get the correct result?

the actual string is ' [{....,"html":"< spanclass=\"icon-pitisscon-service-duliag\">",....}] ' , It's a json format string,
I can't use the json.loads() function because of the \", what should I do? thank

Answer (score 1):

Your `str` is `how{"to"get"this"}position`, it doesnt have `\"` in it; So `find(r'\"')` will return `-1`

```
>>> str = 'how{"to\"get\"this"}position'
>>> str
'how{"to"get"this"}position'
>>>
```

If you want to have str = `how{"to\"get\"this"}position` then;

```
>>> str = r'how{"to\"get\"this"}position'
>>> str
'how{"to\\"get\\"this"}position'
>>> str.find(r'\"')
7
>>>
```

Comment: the actual string is ' {....,"html":"<spanclass=\"icon-pitisscon-service-duliag\"></span>",....}] ' , It's a json format string, I can't add a 'r' in the front of it.  I just want to delete the '\', otherwise I can't use the json.loads() function , what should I do?  thank

Answer (score 0):

You have stored the string wrong (Escape missing). In the case of the string you have stored, if you check str by printing it via `print str`, you'd get `how{"to"get"this"}position` and that is why your search fails. Also the search string should be escaped properly.

The right way would be

```
str = 'how{"to\\"get\\"this"}position'
print str.find('\\"')`
```

Comment: Could also use a raw string `r'how{"to\"get\"this"}position'`

Comment: the actual string is ' {....,"html":"< spanclass=\"icon-pitisscon-service-duliag\"></ span >",....}] ' , It's a json format string,
I can't use the json.loads() function because of the \", what should I do? thank